# Topological spaces as a group under cartesian product

Tags: general-topology, group-theory

I was wondering if one can have a group structure on the set of equivalence classes of (homeomorphic) topological spaces, where the law of composition is directly derived from the Cartesian product. That is, $[A] \times [B] = [A \times B]$.

The identity axiom is satisfied using the space $\{*\}$, since $[X \times \{*\}] = [X]$. Associativity is trivial. Closure is achieved with the product topology. We even have commutativity.

What about inverse? Is there an space $\frac{1}{Y}$ such that $[Y \times \frac{1}{Y}] = [\{*\}]$? How do we write $\frac{1}{Y}$ in terms of $Y$?

Comment: This doesn't even work in set theory, let alone in topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one thing, the operation has an absorbing element in $\emptyset$.

Secondly and more importantly, for all $Y\ne\emptyset$, $X\times Y$ has a subspace homeomorphic to $X$ in $X\times\{y\}$, which $\{*\}$ does not have unless $X=\emptyset$ or $X\cong\{*\}$. Therefore $X=\{*\}$ is the only topological space such that there is a topological space $Y$ such that $X\times Y\cong\{*\}$.